# error of header not found compiling simple C program on osx

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang, gstreamer

So I'm following the GStream tutorial:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=c

I've installed GStreamer 1.16 (tried installing with brew as well as downloading the osx installer from gstreamer website).

When I try to compile the tutorial code on linux:

```
gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

everything works fine, but the same code on my osx fails on missing header files when I try to compile it with gcc or clang:

```
➜  tutorial gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1  -L/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers
basic-tutorial-1.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gst/gst.h' file not found
#include <gst/gst.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

➜  tutorial cc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1  -L/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers
basic-tutorial-1.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gst/gst.h' file not found
#include <gst/gst.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I can see my header files installed:

```
➜  tutorial ls -lsh /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/gst/gst.h
8 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3.7K 20 Apr 01:43 /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/gst/gst.h
```

s

Comment: `gcc` looks in specific places for headers delineated by `<header_file>`. Your path `/Library/...` isn't included in that list of standard places. You can use the `-I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers` option on `gcc`. Or you can include your header path in `C_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to resolve this, and the solution was:
1. installing both the package and the devel package:
gstreamer-1.0-1.16.0-x86_64.pkg
gstreamer-1.0-devel-1.16.0-x86_64.pkg
from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.16.0/

I did this when I installed on ubuntu, but not on osx, since, well, I'm just not use to having devel packages on OSX.

2. compile with `-framework GStreamer` argument and as @lurker suggested, using a `-I` flag

Now this compiles successfully:
    cc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 -framework GStreamer -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Header